# Why the lenses won't follow the glasses?

Tags: rigging

[image]

I have joint both the lenses and the glasses frames.
Before that I Parented the lenses to the glasses.
I also used the same Armature modifier.
All the above without avail.

[badglasses.blend](https://blenderartists.org/uploads/short-url/h7bulDTmzIPbWQAC5PBVGAdHhlh.blend)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I had forgotten to assign the vertices to the "head" Vertex Group in the Armature mod (rolling eyes)! Thanks to [MadeWithFeet](https://blenderartists.org/t/why-the-lenses-wont-follow-the-glasses/1220130/2?u=drpeppercan) from BlenderArtists that called it up.